# Python & PyQt. Clipboard contents to listwidget

Tags: python, pyqt4, clipboard

I am writing my first python app with PyQt4. I'm a beginner in python and generally new to programming. Basically what this app does is monitor clipboard data changes and put/display this as an item in QlistWidget. You can also add items manually by copy pasting the data and clicking the add button. As for monitoring data and automatically adding it in the list widget, I've added a condition where a radio button needs to be toggled for the "monitoring feature" to do its thing. The manual way of adding items works but the monitoring feature doesn't seem to be working. It doesn't add the data (saved in the clipboard) to the list widget. I think I seem to be missing something. 
I'm using Python 2.7 and PyQt 4.11

Here is my code. I removed the extra lines of code (stylesheets & etc~).

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

rbs = False
class Ui_Form(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.resize(385, 277)
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(Form)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout"))
        self.radioButton = QtGui.QRadioButton(Form)
        self.radioButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("radioButton"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.radioButton, 0, 1, 1, 1)

        self.radioButton.toggled.connect(self.toggledRB)

        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 1, 1, 1, 1)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.addItem)

        self.listWidget = QtGui.QListWidget(Form)
        self.listWidget.setEditTriggers(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.DoubleClicked|QtGui.QAbstractItemView.EditKeyPressed|QtGui.QAbstractItemView.SelectedClicked)
        self.listWidget.setSelectionBehavior(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.SelectItems)
        self.listWidget.setMovement(QtGui.QListView.Snap)
        self.listWidget.setUniformItemSizes(False)
        self.listWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("listView"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.listWidget, 2, 0, 1, 2)


        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form", None))

        self.radioButton.setText(_translate("Form", "monitor clipboard", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Add", None))

    def toggledRB(self, bool):
        global rbs
        if self.radioButton.isChecked():
            rbs = True
        else:
            rbs = False
        print rbs

    def addItem(self):
        yyy = self.lineEdit.text()
        self.listWidget.addItem(yyy)

    def dataReceiver(self, intel):
        print 'data is here!'
        self.listWidget.addItem(intel)

class clipboardListener(QObject):  

    @pyqtSlot()  
    def changedSlot(self):
        global rbs
        print 'clipboard data detected!'
        if rbs == True:
            intel = QApplication.clipboard().text()
            print intel
            xxx = Ui_Form()
            xxx.dataReceiver(intel)
        else:
            print 'False Alarm. There was no data. I was just kidding.'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtGui.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()

    listener = clipboardListener()
    QObject.connect(QApplication.clipboard(),SIGNAL("dataChanged()"),listener,SLOT("changedSlot()"))

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `clibpboardListener` you create a new instance of `Ui_Form` and call the `dataReceiver` method on that instead of the `ui` instance you created earlier.

To make this work, you need to pass the object on which to call the `dataReceiver` method to the `clipboardListener`.

Another advice: you should use [new style signals](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html) instead of calling `QObject.connect(...)`. And in python you shouldn't compare to `True` using `==`, either just use the boolean directly as condition, or use `is True` if you want to make it explicitly check for `True` not for the implicit truth value of the compared object.

This works:

```
...

class clipboardListener(QObject):  

    def __init__(self, target):
        QObject.__init__(self)
        self.target = target

    @pyqtSlot()  
    def changedSlot(self):
        global rbs
        print 'clipboard data detected!'
        if rbs:
            intel = QApplication.clipboard().text()
            print intel
            self.target.dataReceiver(intel)
        else:
            print 'False Alarm. There was no data. I was just kidding.'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtGui.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()

    listener = clipboardListener(ui)

    QApplication.clipboard().dataChanged.connect(listener.changedSlot)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```